zksync tokens missing
I want to tell a little story. about 2 years ago. I experienced an unfortunate incident which resulted in my cell phone being stolen by someone. After 2 years, I found a note with my wallet passphrase written on it which was on the stolen cellphone. When I entered the funds into the wallet, I saw that there was a zksyn transaction resulting from an airdrop. and it's exactly the same as the work notes in telegram. I received zksyn tokens, but I don't see my balance... and can't check transaction data. what happen. why has my balance disappeared?


Can you provide additional details, like tokens, address, transactions involved? It could be that tokens migrated to a different address, the wallet was hacked, the price dropped and tokens are worthless, the received tokens were a scam, etc.
